# Filtering "dmesg -w" with cut

Tags: bash

I am trying to filter the output of a command that continuously display logs in a terminal in order to make it more readable for a human.
This function is hardware-specific (and the hardware in question is not very famous), that's why I take the `dmesg -w` command as an example here because I think they have pretty much the same behaviour.

I would like to display only the part after the ' : ' of any message concerning USB. So far I tried to run :

```sh
$ dmesg -w | grep usb | cut -d':' -f2
```

But it's not displaying anything. I have the correct output when I run the same command without the `-d` option of `dmesg`.

Is the `cut` function the correct way to do this ? What am I doing wrong ?

I am not really good with bash, I hope someone can help me :|

Comment: `grep ... | cut ...` can nearly always be replaced with a single `awk`. In this case, `awk -F: '/usb/ {print $2}'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipes are block buffered.

```
stdbuf -oL dmesg -w | grep --line-buffered usb | cut -d: -f2
```

> Is the cut function the correct way to do this ?

Sure.

> What am I doing wrong ?

The output is buffered in internal buffers. Set line buffering for each command to have the output flushed each newline character.

Comment: Okay I didn't know that ! Thank you very much, it works perfectly :)